# what type of data structure would be efficient for searching a process table

Tags: c++, linux, data-structures

i have to search a process table which is populated by the names of processes running on a given set of ip adresses.
currently i am using multimaps in C++ with process name as key and ip address as the value.
is there any other efficient data structure which can do the same task.
also can i gain any sort of parallelism by using pthreads ? if so can anyone point me into a right direction

Answer (score 1):

You do not need parallelism to access a data structure in RAM of several thousand entries. You can just lock over it (making sure only one process/thread accesses it at the time), and ensure the access is sufficient enough. Multimap is okay. A hashmap would be better though.

Answer (score 1):

What is typical query to your table?

Try to use hashmap, it can be faster for big tables.

How do you store names and IP? UTF, string, char*? Ip as uint32 or string?

For readonly structure with a lot of read queries you can benefit from several threads.

upd: use `std::unordered_multimap` from `#include <tr1/unordered_map>`

Comment: and a typical query is finding is a certain process is running or not .. if running report ip addresses

Comment: Use ext/hash_map file and class __gnu_cxx::hash_multimap in gcc 4.1 and earlier

Comment: In new Gcc (e.g. 4.4) use std::unordered_multimap from tr1_impl/unordered_map file

Comment: `tr1/unordered_map` not tr1_impl, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the table, you may find a hash table more efficient than the `multimap` container (which is implemented with a balanced binary tree).

The [hash_multimap](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_multimap.html) data structure implements a hash table STL container, and could be of use to you.

Comment: is hashmap available in GNU compilers or under linux ?

Comment: Its the C++ stdlib, meaning that it is available wherever the standard C++ libraries are. That means practically with all standards compliant compilers for C++.

Comment: hash maps are not standard for c++ (in revisions of 1998 and 2003). They will be included in next c++ standard C++0x.

GCC have a implementation of pre-standard tr1 in its libstdc++, class name `unordered_multimap`. There was also non-standard ext variand: `hash_multimap`

Comment: yeah it gives a lot of warning messages ... i also checked the replacement header file in backward_warning.h but its still giving warnings on compiling. the problem is i cannot submit code that is generating warning is there a way to get rid of the warnings

Comment: What gcc do you have?

Use  std::unordered_multimap from tr1_impl/unordered_map

Comment: `#include <tr1/unordered_map>` and `std::unordered_multimap` must work for gcc 4.3